# How do I assign shortcut to "exec my entire unit test project" in Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, tdd

Attempting to do TDD, I often need to execute all my tests - in my case a single test project that tests all my assemblies.

Currently I'm selecting the project in solution explorer, then pressing a shortcut to "run all tests in debug mode" (which effects the current selection in solution explorer or in code window).

Can I do this test-all in a single shortcut?

Thanks in advance,

Anders

PS: I'm using resharper and nunit, if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, that there is a command, Resharper.UnitTest_RunSolution, that I can map to a keyboard shortcut.

Still, though a fan of resharper, I prefer to use TestDriven.Net for this.

Any suggestions are still very welcomed...